# How to use CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW clock source for timers in linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, time, kernel-module

I have linux 3.14.12 with real-time patch.

I'm writing linux driver for my hardware and in this driver I need to run some code periodically in a precise time intervals. Also I need to use NTP for time updating in my system. The problem is that I'm currently using hrtimer to create time intervals in separate thread like this:

```
static int time_interval_update_thread(void *arg)
{
    int ret = 0;
    __set_current_state(TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE);
    while(!kthread_should_stop())
    {
        ret = schedule_hrtimeout_range(&next_time_int, 0, HRTIMER_MODE_ABS);
        if (ret == -EINTR && !kthread_should_stop())
        {
        }
        else if (ret == 0)
        {
            run_some_code();
            next_time_int = ktime_add_ms(next_time_int, PERIODICAL_INTERVAL_MS);
        }
        __set_current_state(TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is that hrtimer can't use CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW clock source, but CLOCK_MONOTONIC is unsuitable for my task because CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock source is affected by NTP updates.

So is there any way to use CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW clock source to create time intervals?